# finding unexpected looping in cron queue process

Tags: cron

I'm trying to find unexpected looping result from my codes, I'm stuck and confused cuz of this :( , I hope someone might give me suggestion to solve it. here's my codes:

```
function budhapest_cronsync() {
    $jconfig = variable_get('budhapest_params');
    $jurl = $jconfig['budhapest_url'];
    $rids = budhapest_rental(); // get about 200 data in array (array('01' => '201'),..., array('200' => '401')) e.g
    $jsyncobject = new LiveBudhapest($jurl);
    $jstate = $jsyncobject->Sync();

    if ($jstate) {
        $jstatus = 1;
        syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Getting budhapest data ok");
        $jdata = $jsyncobject->getSyncData(); // get about 300 data in array (array('01' => array('alphabet' => array('a','b','c'))),...,(array('300' => array('alphabet' => array('a','b','c'))) e.g

        foreach ($jdata as $key => $value) {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $rids)) {
                $jitem = array(
                    'nid' => $rids[$key],
                    'format' => 'budhapest',
                    'url' => 'http://budhapest.com?prop_id=' . $key
                );

                if (!empty($value['alphabet'])) {
                    enterBudhapest($rids[$key], $value['alphabet']);
                    $jmessages = array(array('messages' => 'Budhapest oke successfully'));
                } else {
                    $jmessages = array(array('messages' => 'No Budhapest available'));
                }

                BudhapestStatus($jitem, $jmessages, $jstatus); //this is log and saved to table
            }
        }
    } else {
        $jstatus = 0;
        syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Getting budhapest data not ok");
    }
}


function budhapest_cron() {
    $items = array();
    // Put everything in a queue for processing.
    $queue = DrupalQueue::get('a');
    $queue1 = DrupalQueue::get('b');
    $queue3 = DrupalQueue::get('Sync Budhapest');
    $queue->createItem($items);
    $queue1->createItem($items);
    $queue3->createItem($items);
}

function budhapest_cron_queue_info() {
    $queues['a'] = array(
        'worker callback' => 'a', // This is the callback function for each queue item.
        'time' => 600, // This is the max run time per cron run in seconds.
    );
    $queues['b'] = array(
        'worker callback' => 'get_rm_month_id', // This is the callback function for each queue item.
        'time' => 180, // This is the max run time per cron run in seconds.
    );
    $queues['Sync Budhapest'] = array(
        'worker callback' => 'budhapest_cronsync', // This is the callback function for each queue item.
        'time' => 600, // This is the max run time per cron run in seconds.
    );
    return $queues;
}
```

question: from my codes above, I expected about 200 logs or less saved to table from this function (BudhapestStatus($jitem, $jmessages, $jstatus)) , but in fact i got thousands of log write to table for once process. why? how could it be?, please help me..

thanks I hope someone will give me suggestion about it.

may be can be clue:
I just saw cron log, end it's written there at message colum "Proccessed 18 times" . so now it's possible, total log is about 3500, 3500/18 = about 196.

why it's processed 18 times and not once?

Comment: You're looping over jdata and creating a log entry each time. Hard to tell where the data is coming from as no info on related classes / objects. Also, the cron_queue name "Sync Budhapest" looks odd to me, I'd lose the space and use and underscore instead (i.e sync_budhapest)

Comment: yes but jdata only has about 300 records, where does thousands log comin? :( really stressed me, it's about 3500 logs.